# Ruby Mail Gem Relay Access from Localhost to Postfix

Tags: ruby, email, mail-gem

I'm on a workstation that doesn't have a `FQDN`.  I'm developing in `Ruby` and using the `mail` gem.  I host my own mail server on the LAN.  I want to forward outgoing emails to this server, off to a gmail recipient (example).

Due to the fact I'm on my workstation (`localhost`), it not being recognized as part of one of my LAN domains (I have a `static IP`), it isn't being recognized by `Postfix` (from my mail server log):

```
Mar 25 08:44:30 machine.mydomain1.com postfix/smtpd[9653]: sacl_check: mbr_user_name_to_uuid(mygmail@gmail.com) failed: No such file or directory
Mar 25 08:44:30 machine.mydomain1.com postfix/cleanup[9657]: sacl_check: mbr_user_name_to_uuid(mygmail@gmail.com) failed: No such file or directory
Mar 25 08:44:30 machine.mydomain1.com postfix/smtp[9658]: 92946D63CD4: to=<mygmail@gmail.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.14, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0.11, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as AE8ECD63CDA)
Mar 25 08:44:31 machine.mydomain1.com postfix/smtp[9661]: AE8ECD63CDA: to=<mygmail@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.195.26]:25, delay=0.52, delays=0/0.01/0.34/0.16, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.195.26] said: 550-5.7.1 [206.248.184.17      11] Our system has detected that this message is 550-5.7.1 not RFC 5322 compliant: 550-5.7.1 'From' header is missing. 550-5.7.1 To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been 550-5.7.1 blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=RfcMessageNonCompliant 550 5.7.1 and review RFC 5322 specifications for more information. a2si7453997iog.10 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command))
Mar 25 08:56:42 machine.mydomain1.com postfix/smtpd[9764]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[192.168.1.4]: 554 5.7.1 <mygmail@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<alpha@mydomain3.ca> to=<mygmail@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mydomain3.ca>
```

I can use the `mail` gem properly on another box that has a `FQDN` just fine.  I just can't seem to get it to work on my workstation.  As it states in the mail server log:

```
'From' header is missing. 550-5.7.1 To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been 550-5.7.1 blocked.
```

I'm assuming this is the machine name **from**, and not the email sender **from**.  How can I tell the mail server that I'm not `localhost`?  I've messed with the `relay` and other `directives` in `postfix` to no avail.  So I'm trying to modify the `Ruby` syntax to make the server recognize me.

Any insight appreciated as to how I can get this to work.  It's my development box and it's working on my production server, but I'd like to have it working on my dev box.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following fixed it, a `config` item for the gem:

```
mail.header['From'] = 'machine.mydomain.com'
```

Also making sure the `relay` information in `postfix` is set properly.